# Formatting Time value to HH:mm:ss.SS in GWT

Tags: java, date, gwt, datetime

I have time format as follows

```
 public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss.SS";
 edition.getEditionDate().format(TIME_FORMAT);
```

The output is as follows:

> 15:02:08.293

How should I get the following output. I don't want to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). I neither want to use substring() method as it is not an efficient way to do it.

> 15:02:08.29

Cannot use SimpleDateFormat as not supported in Gwt client side code.[Methods supported by GWT client side code](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation)

Comment: Check this reference and Format the date using SimpleDateFormat,http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS"); sdf.format(TIME_FORMAT)

Comment: I am curious to know, why you want such precision ?

Comment: Client side display requires two milliseconds in it not 3. :)

Comment: @SanikaJoshi No, your client side may require *1/100* of a second, but milliseconds take - by definition - 3 digits: *1/1000* of a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GWT 2.5 this changes slightly -

1. If you wish to handle this both on server side and client side uniformly then use
   [DateTimeFormat @ Shared](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/DateTimeFormat.html)
2. If you wish to handle this both only on client side then use [DateTimeFormat @ Client](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)

The code will still be -

```
String dateString = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS").format(new Date());
```

Comment: There was a configuration property in my project which was controlling this behaviour and I was unaware of it. You are right. It works. Thank you @SSR.

Comment: You can close the question by accepting the answer and also mention what configuration was inhibiting the display.

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:MM:ss.");
DecimalFormat fractionalformat = new DecimalFormat ("00");

Date date = new Date ();

String str = dateFormat.format (date) + fractionalformat.format (date.getTime () % 1000L / 10L);

System.out.println (str);
```

Comment: PO already mentioned "Cannot use SimpleDateFormat as not supported in Gwt client side code."

Comment: @TheSureshAtta The question was about milliseconds.  I assume that problem of formatting hours minutes and seconds is already solved.  Just posted what works in Java.

Answer (score 1):

To quote SimpleDateFormat javadoc (and variants): "For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount."

So even with 1 or 2 digits specified for milliseconds, you're going to get 3 digits for values greater than or equal to 100 (the majority..).

You'll need to roll your own, and it looks like Mikhail has demonstrated that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String dateString = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS").format(new Date());
System.out.println(dateString);
```

API for [DateTimeFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)